# Why doesn't the 'white-space:normal' property work as expected in <textarea>?

Tags: css, textarea

I know that using white-space:normal can collapse multiple spaces into one, but it doesn't seem to work in the Google browser.

here is my code.

```
            <div>
                <label style="display: block;" for="textarea6">white-space: normal</label>
                <textarea id="textarea6" name="textarea6" rows="5" cols="33" style="white-space: normal;">j jj  jjj </textarea>
                <p style="white-space: normal;">j jj  jjj </p>
            </div>
```

like this.

[All spaces have been reserved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZOUap.png)

All of the CSS styles are listed below.

```
element.style {
    white-space: normal;
}


textarea {
    font-style: ;
    font-variant-ligatures: ;
    font-variant-caps: ;
    font-variant-numeric: ;
    font-variant-east-asian: ;
    font-variant-alternates: ;
    font-weight: ;
    font-stretch: ;
    font-size: ;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-optical-sizing: ;
    font-kerning: ;
    font-feature-settings: ;
    font-variation-settings: ;
    text-rendering: auto;
    color: fieldtext;
    letter-spacing: normal;
    word-spacing: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    text-transform: none;
    text-indent: 0px;
    text-shadow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: start;
    appearance: auto;
    -webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
    resize: auto;
    cursor: text;
    white-space-collapse: preserve;
    text-wrap: wrap;
    overflow-wrap: break-word;
    background-color: field;
    column-count: initial !important;
    writing-mode: horizontal-tb !important;
    margin: 0em;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: -internal-light-dark(rgb(118, 118, 118), rgb(133, 133, 133));
    border-image: initial;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

How can I achieve the expected effect of 'white-space: normal'?

Answer (score 0):

`white-space-collapse: preserve;` Is preserving the space characters. You can delete that, or overwrite it with `white-space-collapse: collapse;`.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I have tried your method, but it still doesn't work. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer.